# Syncfusion Xamarin Carousel infinite scroll

Tags: xamarin, carousel, syncfusion

I try to have Infinite Scroll in Xamarin Syncfusion component SFCarousel.
I try many solution of mine but don't work.

Have you any advise?

I try this code for example:

```
void Handle_SelectionChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.SfCarousel.XForms.SelectionChangedEventArgs {
    if (carousel.SelectedIndex == viewModel.ImageCollection.Count - 1)
    {
        CarouselModel item = viewModel.ImageCollection.First();
        viewModel.ImageCollection.Remove(item);
        viewModel.ImageCollection.Add(item);
    }

    if (carousel.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        CarouselModel item = viewModel.ImageCollection.Last();
        viewModel.ImageCollection.Remove(item);
        viewModel.ImageCollection.Insert(0, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The source code you've provided doesn't even compile. Would you please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52402845/edit) your question and improve its overall quality? See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is a logical example, obviously I can't paste entire solution here... ImageColletion is a collection of image, carousel is the Syncfusion SfCarousel

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Syncfusion component SFCarousel has perspective view. It doesn't have support for infinite scroll,but this can be achieved by using the SfRotator Control.

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/139915/ze/Rotator_Sample-1424193758

Note: I'm working for Syncfusion